# TS creates .d.ts file that is less descriptive

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.0, tsc

I have this input in a .ts file:

```
export const OverSizedItems = <{ [key: string]: OverSizedItemType }>{

  NONE: {
    factor: 1,
    count: 0,
    mooversNeeded: 1,
  },

  ONE: {
    factor: 1.01,
    count: 1,
    mooversNeeded: 4,
  },

  TWO: {
    factor: 1.03,
    count: 2,
    mooversNeeded: 4,
  },

  THREE_PLUS: {
    factor: 1.07,
    count: 5,
    mooversNeeded: 6,
  }

};
```

it transpiles to this:

```
export declare const OverSizedItems: {
    [key: string]: OverSizedItemType;
};
```

but if change the original, and leave off the index signature type info, I get this, which is more what I am looking for:

```
export declare const OverSizedItems: {
    NONE: {
        factor: number;
        count: number;
        mooversNeeded: number;
    };
    ONE: {
        factor: number;
        count: number;
        mooversNeeded: number;
    };
    TWO: {
        factor: number;
        count: number;
        mooversNeeded: number;
    };
    THREE_PLUS: {
        factor: number;
        count: number;
        mooversNeeded: number;
    };

};
```

an enum won't work here because enum's cannot point to objects.

So what can I do to add the index signature but keep all the values?

Answer (score 1):

The best I could come up with is to use the `Record` type, with all of the keys written out in a union, like so:

```
type OverSizedItemKey = "NONE" | "ONE" | "TWO" | "THREE_PLUS"

export const OversizedItems: Record<OverSizedItemKey, OverSizedItemType> = {
  // ...
}
```

`Record` uses a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), so make sure you're familiar with that to know how/why this works.

Comment: thanks let me try it - do you think there's anyway to make the question clearer?

Comment: Sure, maybe give an example of the kind of output you're looking for, but otherwise the question was _mostly_ clear to me